# tag input e javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá,

Minha dúvida é a seguinte

HTML

```
<input id="cakeDonuts" type="number" name="numCake" min="0" value="" onchange="updateOrder()">


<input id="glazedDonuts" type="number" name="numGlazed" min="0" value="" onchange="updateOrder()">
```

JS

```
function updateOrder(){

var numCake = parseInt(document.getElementById("cakeDonuts").value);
var numGlazed = parseInt(document.getElementById("glazedDonuts").value);

}
```

Sabendo que eu tenho uma tag html, input do tipo number, e uma função JS que recebe dados desse input.

minha dúvida é a seguinte, houve a necessidade de fazer a conversão para Inteiro no JS, pois os números estavam sendo entendidos como string, e em vez de somar estava concatenando.

sabendo disso tudo, a real dúvida é, quem é que manda esses numeros como texto?
a própria tag html input do tipo number manda os numeros como texto(String)?

Ou o JS por padrão converte tudo que recebe pra texto(String), E o programador quem trata isso depois?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porquê [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).`value` irá retornar uma string. Você poderia usar `HTMLInputElement`.[valueAsNumber](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-valueasnumber):

**Exemplo**

```js
function updateOrder() {

  var numCake = document.getElementById("cakeDonuts").valueAsNumber;
  console.log(typeof numCake)

}
```

```html
<input id="cakeDonuts" type="number" name="numCake" min="0" value="" onchange="updateOrder()">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado,valueAsNumber seria propriedades ocultas? atributos ocultos ou algo do tipo? no material que eu consulto https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp não consta esse atributo ou propriedade

Comment: Não @NicolasGuilherme, o w3schools na verdade não tem nada a ver com a w3, provavelmente por isso não consta lá.